# Invalid Syntax, Text Based Adventure game. Python (linux)

Tags: python, linux, events, syntax, adventure

I have been working on this text based adventure game using Python. This may be a simple fix, but I am unable to see it. When I add another EVENT in my code, it gives me an INVALID SYNTAX error. For example, when I added EVENT_DOOR2, I get an invalid syntax error, specifically on, door = colored_input():. Below is a snippet of my otherwise long code. Any insight would be helpful! Thank you!

```
def main():
import sys
from colorama import init
init()
init(autoreset=True)
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

def run_event(event):
    text, choices = event
    text_lines = text.split("\n")
    for line in text_lines:
        print(Style.BRIGHT + line)
        print()
    choices = choices.strip()
    choices_lines = choices.split("\n")
    for num, line in enumerate(choices_lines):
        print(Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT + str(num + 1) + ". " + line)
        print()

def colored_input():
    return input(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + "> ")


print ("")
print ("")
print (Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + "                                                                           WELCOME TO THE MAZE                                   ")
print ("")
print ("")
print ("You have found yourself stuck within a dark room, inside this room are 5 doors.. Your only way out..")
print ("")
print ("Do you want to enter door 1,2,3,4, or 5?")
print ("")

EVENT_DOOR1 = ("""
Theres an alien eating what appears to be a human arm, though its so damaged it's hard to be sure. There is a knife next to the alien.
what do you want to do?
""",
"""
Go for the knife
Attack alien before it notices you
""")

EVENT_DOOR2 = ("""You seem to have entered a different world.
Objects and natural elements seem to be alive, grass attempts to wrap around your ankles.
Ahead lies a sword, within what seems to be a large venus fly trap. What should you do?
""","""
Run through this world as fast as you can.
Attempt to grab the sword.
Explore Further.""")


door = colored_input()
if door == "1":
    run_event(EVENT_DOOR1)
elif door == "2":
    run_event(EVENT_DOOR2)


EVENT_ALIEN = ("""
You approach the knife slowly, While the alien is distracted. You finally reach the knife, but as you look up, the alien stares back at you.
You make a move to stab the alien, but he is too quick. With one swift motion, the alien thrusts you into the air.
You land hard, as the alien makes it's way towards you again. What should you do?
""","""
Accept defeat?
Last ditch effort?
""")

EVENT_ALIEN2 = ("""
You catch the alien off-guard. He stumbled and hisses in your direction. You scream in terror before he grabs the knife, and punctures your throat as he rips off your limbs.
""","""
You died.. GAME OVER.. Mistakes can't be made this soon.. OUCH
""")

alien = colored_input()
if alien == "1":
    run_event(EVENT_ALIEN)
elif alien == "2":
    run_event(EVENT_ALIEN2)


restart=input(Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + "Start over? Yes or No? ").lower()
if restart == "yes":
    sys.stderr.write("\x1b[2J\x1b[H")
    main()

else:
    exit()

main()
```

Comment: Where is the closing parenthesis?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Wow, yep, that's it. Guess I was thinking too hard

Comment: In general, whenever you see a SyntaxError on a line that looks perfectly fine, look for a missing `)`, `]`, or `}` on a previous line. Of course that isn't _always_ the problem, but it is very often, often enough that it's worth getting into the habit of checking that before you beat your head against the desk. (And also, if you can configure your editor/IDE to help you with that, do it.)